# Using "ng new myproj -sd src/client" breaks the angular cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-components

I am trying to follow [a tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-samples) that uses the angular cli. When generating a new component, I get a strange error that I try to analyze/resolve. I need some aid in resolving the issue...

To isolate the matter, I run:

```
ng new myproj -sd foo
cd myproj
ng g c bar
```

and this is fine. First a new angular project is created. Then a new module 'bar' is created in `foo/app/bar/bar.component.ts`. But then I try

```
ng new myproj -sd src/client
cd myproj
ng g c bar
```

and that gives me the error...

```
Error: Could not find an NgModule for the new component. Use the skip-import option to skip importing components in NgModule.
Could not find an NgModule for the new component. Use the skip-import option to skip importing components in NgModule.
```

I suspect something is awefully wrong, because writing

```
ng g c bar --skip-import=true
```

resolves into `create src/client/src/client/app/bar/bar.component.ts (247 bytes)`.

My conclusion is that the angular gets REALLY confused by the source-dir `src/client` and doubles it. Therefore, it cannot find the module-file and produces an error. That sounds to me as a bug in the angular cli, but since I am a novice on angular, I wonder if I am thinking something wrong here.

Is my conclusion true that "-sd src/client" breaks the angular cli? Why? Why not?

---

ps...

```
ng version 
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
@angular/cli: 1.4.7
node: 6.9.4
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.4.5
@angular/common: 4.4.5
@angular/compiler: 4.4.5
@angular/core: 4.4.5
@angular/forms: 4.4.5
@angular/http: 4.4.5
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.5
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.5
@angular/router: 4.4.5
@angular/cli: 1.4.7
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.5
@angular/language-service: 4.4.5
typescript: 2.3.4
```